# SQLite python does not update table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("testDB")
cur = con.cursor()

#cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test_table (id integer primary key, data text)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?, ?)', (76, 'MyData'))
```

when I run this script it does not update table. But when I do the same insertion using sqlite3 commandline in Linux, it updates. Why is it so or there anything I am making wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
# Save (commit) the changes
con.commit()
```

Comment: con.commit() this should be done after everything is finished, or can I commit after each con.execute() statement???

Comment: If another program want to see the data immediately, you should commit immediately. Otherwise you can commit at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try commiting after the insert clause?

Comment: con.commit() work but con.commit() this should be done after everything is finished, or can I commit after each con.execute() statement??? what is the main purpos of commit?

Comment: the 'commit' is to finish all the alteration in your table...but if you want back at the last status you use the 'rollback clause'