# Python's sqlite3 module not consolidating my database changes

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to populate a database with latlon weather data for future consultation. I am doing this via the sqlite3 python module.

At the moment, I am able to create the table (a resulting .db file is visible after program execution). I am also able to consult rows after insertion, so I'm sure my `cursor.execute` lines are working.

Unfortunately, after program execution, upon consulting the database with a `"select * from table"` statement, nothing appears (even though the same command worked beforehand, while the program executed). In fact, when dumping the sqlite3 file, I only get the create statement.

What could be wrong? I get no errors or warnings.

The code itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import numpy
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import sqlite3

# Config variables.
N = 0
E = -30
S = -30
W = -60

ncfile = sys.argv[1];
ncdata = Dataset(ncfile,'r',format='NETCDF4')

sst = ncdata.variables['sea_surface_temperature']
lat = ncdata.variables['lat']
lon = ncdata.variables['lon']

# Data reshaping.
lat = lat[:]
lon = lon[:]
sst = sst[:]

c_lat = numpy.argwhere((lat <= N) & (lat >= S))
c_lon = numpy.argwhere((lon <= E) & (lon >= W))

conn = sqlite3.connect('sst.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create the database table.
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE current(lat real, lon real, sst real)""")

sqlite3.register_adapter(numpy.float64, float)
sqlite3.register_adapter(numpy.float32, float)
for lati in c_lat:
    for loni in c_lon:
        latn = lati[0]
        lonn = loni[0]
        lat_db = lat[latn]
        lon_db = lon[lonn]
        sst_db = sst[0,lonn][latn]

        values = (lat_db,lon_db,sst_db)
        if type(sst_db) != numpy.float64:
            continue

        c.execute("INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)",values)

# Test if data was inserted. (it is!)
c.execute("SELECT * FROM current")
print c.fetchall()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite python does not update table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804073/sqlite-python-does-not-update-table)

Comment: Perfect! Apperantly I did not search the correct terms.