# How do I fix to update my values using SQL in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently studying Python and we're using Pycharm and I'm fairly new to this. My problem is whenever I want to update my row that I've created, it doesn't actually update. I have no clue how to fix it.

This is my current code right now:

```
def update_row(db_cursor):
    sql = "update patient_profile set zip_code = ?, no_shows = ? where occupation = ?"
    occupation = input("Enter the occupation (str) for your patient profile you would like to update: ")
    zip_code = int(input("Enter your new zipcode (int) : "))
    no_shows = int(input("Enter a new number for how many times you think you have no-showed (int): "))
    tuple_of_values = (zip_code,  no_shows,   occupation)
    db_cursor.execute(sql, tuple_of_values)
    print("Row updated.")
```

Any help for a beginner would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When you execute an sql update, those changes are just temporary unless you commit them.  Some databases automatically do the commit for you, and some don't.  Looks like this one doesn't.  Generally `commit()` is a method on the database connection, not on the cursor.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9804073/494134 for one example.

Comment: I would advise not using `input()` to prompt the user and instead hardcode the vaules to save your work of typing them in every time.